# Why has the one on one chat option been removed?

Tags: discussion, chat

If I am not wrong, the one on one chat option has been removed. Why did that happen? Please let me know if we still have this option.

Second question: why can't we chat with new users on Stack Overflow?

Comment: so many dislikes ,does  that means we still have a chat option :)

Comment: What do you actually mean?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean - do you mean the "let us continue this discussion in chat" feature? That shows up only for very long comment threads.

Comment: @Pekka웃 No , we had a option earlier where we can go to somebody's profile and chat with the user ...that I am asking

Comment: I've never seen that option before. Are you sure it was on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I'm guessing the OP means that if you go to a user's *chat* profile, you can invite that user to a new room... which is still there...

Comment: @Jon Ahh, I see.

Answer (score 5):

It hasn't been removed - it's still available on a user's **chat** profile.

[image]

However, the user has to have 20+ rep, have an active chat account (ie: not currently suspended), and have been active in chat recently.

Comment: where can i find this option ? link please

Comment: @YoYo [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5336818/yo-yo)